# Как поменять местами ключи и значения в объекте? JS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, объекты

```
const myObj = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
}; 

function swap(obj) {
  const res = {};

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    // Как здесь записать в объект res нужные ключи и значения?        
  });    
  return res;
};

swap(myObj);

// на выходе нужно получить { 1: "first", 2: "second", 3: "third" }
```

Comment: `key` - ключ, `obj[key]` - значение.

Comment: OMG `res[obj[key]] = key;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> // Как здесь записать в объект res нужные ключи и значения?

ключ уже есть, он хранится в параметре `key`, значение можно получить с помощью [скобочной нотации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#Bracket_notation): `obj[key]`.

Осталось только сохранить нужное значение:

```
obj[obj[key]] = key;
```

```js
const myObj = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
};

function swap(obj) {
  const res = {};

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(value) {
    var key = obj[value];
    res[key] = value;
  });
  return res;
};

console.log(swap(myObj));
```

---

Также, с помощью метода [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), можно получить сразу массив в котором элементами будут массивы `[key, value]`.

В этом случае код станет выглядеть проще

```
return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [value,key]) => {
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
}, {})
```

Еще более упростить код, можно воспользовавшись методом [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromentries), который принимает на вход список пар ключ, значение, аналогичный тому, который возвращает [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

В этом случае достаточно поменять местами ключ и значение, например в процессе выполнения метода [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key,value])=>[value,key])
```

---

Так же можно обойтись без создания нового объекта, удаляя ненужные свойства во время обхода и добавляя нужные

```js
const myObj = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
};

function swap(obj) {
  for (var key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    obj[obj[key]] = key;
    delete obj[key];
  }
};

swap(myObj);

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 12):

Один из вариантов это воспользоваться методом [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const myObj = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
}

const result = {}

Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  result[value] = key
})

console.log(result)
// { "1": "first", "2": "second", "3": "third" }
```

*Но, если значения будут пересекаться, то этот вариант не будет работать корректно, например:*

```
const myObj = { "first": 1, "second": 1, "third": 2 }
```

*т.е он подойдет только если значения у исходного объекта будут уникальными.*

Comment: если значения будут пересекаться, никакой вариант не подойдет, так как в объекте не может быть повторяющихся свойств.

Comment: @Grundy, если значения будут пересекаться, `if(value in result) throw ...` -- по крайней мере вовремя заметим. Можно и `merge` функцию вторым аргументом передать, и давать ей ключи в алфавитном порядке для определенности.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, здесь нужно отталкиваться от того, какой результат нужен

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({a: 1, b: 2}).map(([k,v])=>[v,k])))
```